# Como validar um input type number para aceitar apenas números?

Tags: html5, input

Estou querendo configurar o input number do html5 para aceitar apenas números, mas está aceitando a letra "e" e também ",."

Estou fazendo dessa maneira:

```html
<label for="txtHora">Hora limite</label>
<input type="number" name="txtHora" id="txtHora" value="" maxlength="2" min="0" max="59" pattern="[0-9]{2}" class="form-control form-control-sm numeros data">
```

Como consigo deixar somente números? Porquê está aceitando esses caracteres?

Comment: Ele aceita `e` e `.` porque vc pode digitar números em notação científica - ex: `2.5e3` para o número 2500. Mas isso depende do browser, se não me engano o Firefox deixa digitar qualquer coisa (e o campo se torna inválido). Se quer usar o `pattern`, terá que usar `type=text`, pois o `type=number` não suporta esse atributo: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern

Comment: Cara esse input é para vc marcar apenas hora? Hora não tem `.` ou `,`... vc deveria se preocupar é com os `:` não acha?

Comment: @hugocsl neste caso aí eu não preciso me preocupar com os ":" porque só interessa a parte da hora mesmo, que será digitada pelo usuário.

Comment: @hkotsubo ajudou sim, compreendi que o pattern só serve para validar quando o form é enviado, no meu caso seria para evitar que algo inválido fosse digitado. Agradeço a atenção de vocês, obrigado pela informação que vocês me passaram, vou alterar aqui e fazer um script para evitar que algo indesejado seja digitado no campo.